# Account doesn't sync with AD - MOSS - WSS User Profile sync

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I'm working on a project that uses MOSS 2007.  We have user profiles set up to sync from AD and see the following behavior.

Take the user Jane Doe and her account MYDOMAIN\JaneDoe

1. She becomes part of a site collection
2. Her settings look fine when clicking My Settings or when another user looks at her info by clicking on her under People and Groups
3. She gets married and is renamed Jane Married with account MYDOMAIN\JaneMarried
4. The Shared Service Provider User Profile incremental import occurs
5. The profile looks good in the Shared Service Provider
6. The User Profile Synchronization Timer Job runs
7. The changes to Name and User name show properly in the My Settings or People and Groups but the Account field still has the old value until the new id (MYDOMAIN\JaneMarried) is added to the All Users.

Any ideas on where we might be missing something from a config standpoint?  Or is there a SharePoint bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the stsadm command migrateuser:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262141.aspx

We have seen this before at my current client where some women will change their name due to marriage and the profile import will work fine for some but fail for the other.  This command typically will fix that issue.

Comment: This is the route I went to fix it.  I'm actually planning to use the SPFarm API instead of the stsadm command but it should do the trick based on testing so far.  See this response I got on technet for more info, too:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/28ea0acd-d7b2-4bca-b18f-33f5b6911503/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `SharePoint AD Sync`. Have not used it before but your question reminds me that tool.

Only for your information.